# How did main character of "The Door Into Summer" take his own place in cryo chamber?

Tags: time-travel, robert-a-heinlein, the-door-into-summer

Long story short, in *[The Door Into Summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Door_into_Summer)*, the main character freezes himself and wakes up in the future. Then he goes back to the past using an experimental time travel, does his clever business, and comes to the same cryo facility to sleep back to the future. Wouldn't the staff of the cryo company be surprised when 2 Dan Davises show up on the day of contract to be freezed?

Comment: This is one of my favorite books of Heinlein's. I'll have to reread this again, but from my recollection he Dan did a great job avoiding himself in his past and then with what he remembered of the his future, he planned well enough with his nudist lawyer friends to create his future company and his entry back into the future. Will have to find my copy and reread the last part.

Comment: Speaking of Davises, the title of this question looks like it was written by Manuel Garcia O'Kelly-Davis. Except Mannie would probably leave out "his" as well.

Answer (score 10):

He doesn't use the same facility the second time. The first time, Belle changes his paperwork for Mutual Assurance to instead go to Master Insurance (same number of characters since they had to do this on a typewriter, and a subsidiary of Mannix, which Belle used to work for and therefore had contacts) and has him checked in there. The second time, he goes to the facility that he was originally going to use the first time, Mutual Assurance.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning a bit clearer?

Comment: I listened to the book on Youtube until I could find that their answer was correct, so I deleted mine to fix this one.

Comment: This answer is correct.

Comment: If I remember correctly the procedure was very expensive and he spent all his money on that. Surely he couldn't simply come to Master Insurance, show his forged papers and do it without payment?